# FactoryGirl loses belongs_to built in Model.before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot, before-save

Given this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_profile  
  before_create { build_user_profile }
end
```

and this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  end
end
```

when I do:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

`FactoryGirl` loses the `@user.user_profile` association (it is `nil`) and I have to call `@user.reload`

This slows my tests somewhat, since a logged-in user is required for most tests. I've tried having the factory (re)create the association in `before/after(:build/:create)` to no avail.

How can I get `FactoryGirl` to respect `ActiveRecord` before/after hooks?

### Edit:

`reload` actually was not sufficient, I had to do this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    after(:create) do |user|
      user.create_user_profile
      user.save
    end
  end
end
```

Using `FactoryGirl`s own `association` method does not work so long as the `User` model has `before_create { build_user_profile }`.

Comment: FactoryGirls association method should work, can you explain what's the problem in using association method .

Comment: I can't explain it. I couldn't figure it out. If I remove the `before_create` from the model, than FactoryGirl's association method works as expected. With the `before_create` in, `User`s created by `FactoryGirl` don't get a `user_profile` whether or not I add in the FactoryGirl association method.

Answer (score 1):

`FactoryGirl` relies on `new` and `save!` to create model instances, so it's not calling your `create` method and therefore not invoking your `create` hooks. You'll have to refactor the creation of your associations in your model or adjust your factories in order to ensure the creation of the associations.

Comment: `create_user_profile` will result in orphan records when the `User` is invalid.

Comment: by the way, everything works as expected in the actual app, or if I for example write a spec where I don't use FactoryGirl.